# Using PHP CURL for parsing sites with heavy load?

Tags: php, parsing, curl

I use PHP CURL for parsing site with heavy load (This site even rarely openes in browser). In the result I have server response code 503 or 0 (nothing).
Maybe You can give me advice or tell me some CURL features for getting normal server response?

There's my CURL options:

```
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_REFERER => $url,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 1800,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION => "curlHeaderCallback",
    CURLOPT_COOKIE => Cookies::arrayToString(Cookies::instance()->load()),
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; U; ru) Presto/2.9.168 Version/11.50",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
);
```

The problem is that I can't get response with page code.

I have 2 variants:
1. Server didn't answer;
2. In server's answer I get page with code 503 "server is overloaded".

CurlHeaderCallback() code:

```
`function curlHeaderCallback($ch, $str)
{
if (strncmp($str, "Set-Cookie:", 11) === 0)
    {
    $cookie = trim(substr($str, 11));
    list($cookie, $options) = explode(";", $cookie, 2);
    list($key, $value) = explode("=", $cookie, 2);
    Cookies::instance()->set($key, $value);
    }
if (trim($str) == "")
    {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, Cookies::arrayToString(Cookies::instance()->load()));
    }
return (strlen($str));
}`
```

My actions are:
    `$response = curl_exec($ch);
    $info     = curl_getinfo($ch);`

I have no response and `$info["http_code"]` or second variant: in response I have page 503 code and `$info["http_code"] = 503`

Oh, one more option is:

```
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30
```

Diagram is here: http://s61.radikal.ru/i172/1212/d6/33471472ee8e.png

Comment: What is the problem you are having?  Are you saying that you're getting timeouts when you try to fetch the page?  What is in `$headers`?  What is the code for `curlHeaderCallback()`?

Comment: CurlHeaderCallback() code:
'function curlHeaderCallback($ch, $str)
    {
    if (strncmp($str, "Set-Cookie:", 11) === 0)
        {
        $cookie = trim(substr($str, 11));
        list($cookie, $options) = explode(";", $cookie, 2);
        list($key, $value) = explode("=", $cookie, 2);
        Cookies::instance()->set($key, $value);
        }
    if (trim($str) == "")
        {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, Cookies::arrayToString(Cookies::instance()->load()));
        }
    return (strlen($str));
    }'

Comment: Rather than post CurlHeaderCallback() in a comment, you can go back and edit your original post and add it there.  It's easier to read, and others will be able to more easily find it.

Comment: if the server is giving you a 503 error surely there's nothing you can do other than try again later unless you actually run the server giving the 503 error?

Comment: @Stu, yes. about 80% requests server no answers and about 20% requests server answers "503".
Hm, about 80% requests losts. I think it losts at dns with firewall (it's another server). [See scheme in Question]

Comment: if the server's responding a 503 20% of this time I think the other 80% of calls are probably a timeout issue or some sort, hence no response at all from the server. Unfortunately not a lot you can do about that

Comment: @Stu , your opinion is that I can have positive results only by sending a big count of requests?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend sending hundreds or requests to a server in a short time, that's likely to lead to bad things, do you know the reason the server is so inaccessible?

Comment: @Stu, I think there main problem is web server connections limit + thousands of users (and parsers) that work with it.
May be you can help me and recommend curl options for sending "hundreds of requests"? Because I understand in php as "a pig understand in oranges" :)

Comment: @Stu , sorry, I was inattentive. You wrote: "I **wouldn't** recommend sending hundreds...". May be you can tell me, what CURL options I can use when I work with such overloaded server?

Answer (score 2):

If you're just after the http code, you need to use [curl_getinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) using `CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE`, an example being;

```
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$response = curl_exec($handle);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

Comment: When site is not overloaded my parsing works great. All works fine.

Comment: Ah, ok, well in that case I don't think there's a lot you can do about the issue if a foreign server timing out, unless of course you run the server that's timing out, but that's a whole new question! :)

Comment: _unless of course you run the server that's timing out_
did you mean "Unless you control the server that's timing out"? This meaning?

Comment: yes, exactly, if you don't control the server that is timing out, I don't see there's a lot you can do to solve the problem unfortunately :(